# How to generate Email Automatically ,After Registration In Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have A models.py as this

**models.py**

```
class User(AbstractUser, BaseModel):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    addresss=models.CharField(max_length=40)
    phoneno=models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    email=models.EmailField()
    password=models.CharField(max_length=40)
    re_password=models.CharField(max_length=40)
    gender=models.IntegerField(choices=gender_choice,default='0')
```

**serializers.py**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('full_name','id','addresss','phoneno','email','gender')
```

**views.py**

```
class StudentViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Student.objects.all()

    serializer_class = StudentSerializer
    http_methods = ['get', 'post','put','delete']


    def create(self, request):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        row = serializer.data

        user=User.objects.get_or_create( 
            defaults={'full_name':row['user']['full_name'],'addresss':row['addresss'],
            'phoneno':row['phoneno'],'password':row['password'] ,'re_password':row[['re_password'],
            'gender':row['gender'] ,'username':username})
```

**My Question**:

After Registering Student, I want to generate an email like his/her(address@gmail.com).

How can i do This ?

Comment: You want to create an email address or send an email to student registered?

Comment: Like already asked : create email or send email ? But one thing: you store user's password in plain text ( no need to store re-password). I would suggest you to see how django creates users and follow same/similar path otherwise you will have issues soon.

Comment: not wanna to send just i wannt to create